# Prove that DE is the perpendicular bisector of GH

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

While I was finding a solution for a question that was posted in StackExchange recently, I found this.

[image]

The circles with centres $D$ and $E$ in the picture are identical and the radius of these circles is $R$.
$GFIH$ is a square that is inscribed in the common area for these two circles.

I can see that $GH$ is bisected by the line joining the centres of the circles (segment $DE$). And also I proved it using geogebra.

I tried to prove it using geometry but I couldn't.

Here is my approach

[image]

I already know that the common chord $JK$ is perpendicular to the line joining the centres.

So I created a rhombus $DJEK$ the I found the lengths of the diagonals using $30^\circ-60^\circ-90^\circ$ triangle rule. But that didn't help me.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem (Prefered without trigonometry)

Thank you for attending my question !

Comment: I wonder why you do not use the same software for labeling angles.

Comment: @ACB It is a little unfamiliar to me to see angles marked in text labels 

Comment: It really depends on what your starting point is. If your starting point is that two sides of the square are parallel to and two sides are perp to the segment joining the centers then it is straightforward. Connect $E$ to $G$ and $H$. $EG = EH = R$ and $ED \perp HG$. So $ED$ must bisect $HG$.

Comment: Otherwise first show that sides of a square cannot be slanted to the segment joining the centers. Then follow with the above proof.

Comment: @Bometh you are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a theorem that states that the perpendicular bisector of a chord passes through the center of a circle. So consider chord $GH$ for the circle with $E$ as the center. If we construct perpendicular bisector to $GH$, we know that it will go thru $E$. But because it's a square, this bisector will also be  perpendicular bisector to $IF$. Applying the same theorem to the other circle, it must go thru the point $D$.

Comment: is there any method to prove the theorem

Comment: @Bometh: all points equidistant from $G$ and $H$ lie on the perpendicular bisector. Because theses two points belong to a circle, and the distance from the center of the circle to  $G$ and $H$ is the same, the center must lie on the perpendicular bisector.